# Debian 8.0 Not working after installation in vm

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I installed Debian 8.0 recently in vmware workstation 16.
When Debian boots up after instalation I see the following picture:
[image: Boot Failure.]

I know this version of Debian was made in 2015, but I really want to use it.
Please help! (It does the same thing in live cd mode.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrupted installation ISO? Maybe try [8.11 instead](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/8.11.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-mac-8.11.0-amd64-netinst.iso). There's no point in using 8.0 which saw many updates after it.